# Why does the anchor tag take space and push everything to the right?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am doing tutorials on CSS and am working with the following [github project](https://github.com/jonasschmedtmann/advanced-css-course)

The final look would be [like this](https://nexter.netlify.com/) but when someone clicks on view properties, you would be taken to the home listen further down in the page.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:300,400,400i|Nunito:300,300i" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png">

    <title>nexter &mdash; your home, your freedom</title>
</head>
<body class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <button class="nav-btn"></button>
    </div>

    <header class="header">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Nexter logo" class="header__logo">
        <h3 class="heading-3">Your own home:</h3>
        <h1 class="heading-1">The ultimate personal freedom</h1>
        <a href="#homesanchor"><button class="btn header__btn">View our properties</button></a>
        <div class="header__seenon-text">Seen on</div>
        <div class="header__seenon-logos">
            <img src="img/logo-bbc.png" alt="Seen on logo 1">
            <img src="img/logo-forbes.png" alt="Seen on logo 2">
            <img src="img/logo-techcrunch.png" alt="Seen on logo 3">
            <img src="img/logo-bi.png" alt="Seen on logo 4">
        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="features">
        <div class="feature">
            <svg class="feature__icon">
                <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-global"></use>
            </svg>
            <h4 class="heading-4 heading-4--dark">World's best luxury homes</h4>
            <p class="feature__text">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur distinctio necessitatibus pariatur voluptatibus.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="feature">
            <svg class="feature__icon">
                <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-trophy"></use>
            </svg>
            <h4 class="heading-4 heading-4--dark">Only the best properties</h4>
            <p class="feature__text">Voluptatum mollitia quae. Vero ipsum sapiente molestias accusamus rerum sed a eligendi aut quia.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="feature">
            <svg class="feature__icon">
                <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-map-pin"></use>
            </svg>
            <h4 class="heading-4 heading-4--dark">All homes in in top locations</h4>
            <p class="feature__text">Tenetur distinctio necessitatibus pariatur voluptatibus quidem consequatur harum.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="feature">
            <svg class="feature__icon">
                <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-key"></use>
            </svg>
            <h4 class="heading-4 heading-4--dark">New home in one week</h4>
            <p class="feature__text">Vero ipsum sapiente molestias accusamus rerum. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="feature">
            <svg class="feature__icon">
                <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-presentation"></use>
            </svg>
            <h4 class="heading-4 heading-4--dark">Top 1% realtors</h4>
            <p class="feature__text">Quidem consequatur harum, voluptatum mollitia quae. Tenetur distinctio necessitatibus pariatur voluptatibus.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="feature">
            <svg class="feature__icon">
                <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-lock"></use>
            </svg>
            <h4 class="heading-4 heading-4--dark">Secure payments on nexter</h4>
            <p class="feature__text">Pariatur voluptatibus quidem consequatur harum, voluptatum mollitia quae.</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="homes">
      <a name="homesanchor"></a>
        <div class="home">
            <img src="img/house-1.jpeg" alt="House 1" class="home__img">
            <svg class="home__like">
                <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-heart-full"></use>
            </svg>
            <h5 class="home__name">Beautiful Familiy House</h5>
            <div class="home__location">
                <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-map-pin"></use>
                </svg>
                <p>USA</p>
            </div>
            <div class="home__rooms">
                <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-profile-male"></use>
                </svg>
                <p>5 rooms</p>
            </div>
            <div class="home__area">
                <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-expand"></use>
                </svg>
                <p>325 m<sup>2</sup></p>
            </div>
            <div class="home__price">
                <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-key"></use>
                </svg>
                <p>$1,200,000</p>
            </div>
            <button class="btn home__btn">Contact realtor</button>
        </div>


        <div class="home">
            <img src="img/house-2.jpeg" alt="House 2" class="home__img">
            <svg class="home__like">
                <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-heart-full"></use>
            </svg>
            <h5 class="home__name">Modern Glass Villa</h5>
            <div class="home__location">
                <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-map-pin"></use>
                </svg>
                <p>Canada</p>
            </div>
            <div class="home__rooms">
                <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-profile-male"></use>
                </svg>
                <p>6 rooms</p>
            </div>
            <div class="home__area">
                <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-expand"></use>
                </svg>
                <p>450 m<sup>2</sup></p>
            </div>
            <div class="home__price">
                <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-key"></use>
                </svg>
                <p>$2,750,000</p>
            </div>
            <button class="btn home__btn">Contact realtor</button>
        </div>

        <div class="home">
            <img src="img/house-3.jpeg" alt="House 3" class="home__img">
            <svg class="home__like">
                <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-heart-full"></use>
            </svg>
            <h5 class="home__name">Cozy Country House</h5>
            <div class="home__location">
                <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-map-pin"></use>
                </svg>
                <p>UK</p>
            </div>
            <div class="home__rooms">
                <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-profile-male"></use>
                </svg>
                <p>4 rooms</p>
            </div>
            <div class="home__area">
                <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-expand"></use>
                </svg>
                <p>250 m<sup>2</sup></p>
            </div>
            <div class="home__price">
                <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-key"></use>
                </svg>
                <p>$850,000</p>
            </div>
            <button class="btn home__btn">Contact realtor</button>
        </div>

        <div class="home">
            <img src="img/house-4.jpeg" alt="House 4" class="home__img">
            <svg class="home__like">
                <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-heart-full"></use>
            </svg>
            <h5 class="home__name">Large Rustical Villa</h5>
            <div class="home__location">
                <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-map-pin"></use>
                </svg>
                <p>Portugal</p>
            </div>
            <div class="home__rooms">
                <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-profile-male"></use>
                </svg>
                <p>6 rooms</p>
            </div>
            <div class="home__area">
                <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-expand"></use>
                </svg>
                <p>480 m<sup>2</sup></p>
            </div>
            <div class="home__price">
                <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-key"></use>
                </svg>
                <p>$1,950,000</p>
            </div>
            <button class="btn home__btn">Contact realtor</button>
        </div>

        <div class="home">
            <img src="img/house-5.jpeg" alt="House 5" class="home__img">
            <svg class="home__like">
                <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-heart-full"></use>
            </svg>
            <h5 class="home__name">Majestic Palace House</h5>
            <div class="home__location">
                <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-map-pin"></use>
                </svg>
                <p>Germany</p>
            </div>
            <div class="home__rooms">
                <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-profile-male"></use>
                </svg>
                <p>18 rooms</p>
            </div>
            <div class="home__area">
                <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-expand"></use>
                </svg>
                <p>4230 m<sup>2</sup></p>
            </div>
            <div class="home__price">
                <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-key"></use>
                </svg>
                <p>$9,500,000</p>
            </div>
            <button class="btn home__btn">Contact realtor</button>
        </div>

        <div class="home">
            <img src="img/house-6.jpeg" alt="House 6" class="home__img">
            <svg class="home__like">
                <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-heart-full"></use>
            </svg>
            <h5 class="home__name">Modern Familiy Apartment</h5>
            <div class="home__location">
                <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-map-pin"></use>
                </svg>
                <p>Italy</p>
            </div>
            <div class="home__rooms">
                <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-profile-male"></use>
                </svg>
                <p>3 rooms</p>
            </div>
            <div class="home__area">
                <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-expand"></use>
                </svg>
                <p>180 m<sup>2</sup></p>
            </div>
            <div class="home__price">
                <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-key"></use>
                </svg>
                <p>$600,000</p>
            </div>
            <button class="btn home__btn">Contact realtor</button>
        </div>
    </section>


    <section class="gallery">
        <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--1"><img src="img/gal-1.jpeg" alt="Gallery image 1" class="gallery__img"></figure>
        <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--2"><img src="img/gal-2.jpeg" alt="Gallery image 2" class="gallery__img"></figure>
        <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--3"><img src="img/gal-3.jpeg" alt="Gallery image 3" class="gallery__img"></figure>
        <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--4"><img src="img/gal-4.jpeg" alt="Gallery image 4" class="gallery__img"></figure>
        <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--5"><img src="img/gal-5.jpeg" alt="Gallery image 5" class="gallery__img"></figure>
        <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--6"><img src="img/gal-6.jpeg" alt="Gallery image 6" class="gallery__img"></figure>
        <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--7"><img src="img/gal-7.jpeg" alt="Gallery image 7" class="gallery__img"></figure>
        <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--8"><img src="img/gal-8.jpeg" alt="Gallery image 8" class="gallery__img"></figure>
        <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--9"><img src="img/gal-9.jpeg" alt="Gallery image 9" class="gallery__img"></figure>
        <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--10"><img src="img/gal-10.jpeg" alt="Gallery image 10" class="gallery__img"></figure>
        <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--11"><img src="img/gal-11.jpeg" alt="Gallery image 11" class="gallery__img"></figure>
        <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--12"><img src="img/gal-12.jpeg" alt="Gallery image 12" class="gallery__img"></figure>
        <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--13"><img src="img/gal-13.jpeg" alt="Gallery image 13" class="gallery__img"></figure>
        <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--14"><img src="img/gal-14.jpeg" alt="Gallery image 14" class="gallery__img"></figure>


    </section>

    <footer class="footer">
        <ul class="nav">
                <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Find your dream home</a></li>
                <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Request proposal</a></li>
                <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Download home planner</a></li>
                <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Contact us</a></li>
                <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Submit your property</a></li>
                <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Come work with us!</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p class="copyright">
            &copy; Copyright 2017 by Jonas Schmedtmann. Feel free to use this project for your own purposes. This does NOT apply if you plan to produce your own course or tutorials based on this project.
        </p>
    </footer>
</body>
```

My CSS is as follows (stored as style.css)

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit; }

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 75em) {
    html {
      font-size: 50%; } }

body {
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
  color: #6D5D4B;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.6; }

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 80vh min-content 40vw repeat(3, min-content);
  grid-template-columns: [sidebar-start] 8rem [sidebar-end full-start] minmax(6rem, 1fr) [center-start] repeat(8, [col-start] minmax(min-content, 14rem) [col-end]) [center-end] minmax(6rem, 1fr) [full-end]; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 62.5em) {
    .container {
      grid-template-rows: 6rem 80vh min-content 40vw repeat(3, min-content);
      grid-template-columns: [full-start] minmax(6rem, 1fr) [center-start] repeat(8, [col-start] minmax(min-content, 14rem) [col-end]) [center-end] minmax(6rem, 1fr) [full-end]; } }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 50em) {
    .container {
      grid-template-rows: 6rem calc(100vh - 6rem); } }

.heading-1, .heading-2, .heading-3, .heading-4 {
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400; }

.heading-1 {
  font-size: 4.5rem;
  color: #f9f7f6;
  line-height: 1; }

.heading-2 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 1; }
  .heading-2--light {
    color: #f9f7f6; }
  .heading-2--dark {
    color: #54483A; }

.heading-3 {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  color: #c69963;
  text-transform: uppercase; }

.heading-4 {
  font-size: 1.9rem; }
  .heading-4--light {
    color: #f9f7f6; }
  .heading-4--dark {
    color: #54483A; }

.btn {
  background-color: #c69963;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 1.8rem 3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .2s; }
  .btn:hover {
    background-color: #B28451; }

.mb-sm {
  margin-bottom: 2rem; }

.mb-md {
  margin-bottom: 3rem; }

.mb-lg {
  margin-bottom: 4rem; }

.mb-hg {
  margin-bottom: 8rem; }

.sidebar {
  background-color: #c69963;
  grid-column: sidebar-start / sidebar-end;
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 62.5em) {
    .sidebar {
      grid-column: 1 / -1;
      grid-row: 1 / 2;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      align-items: center; } }

.nav-btn {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 2px;
  width: 4.5rem;
  margin-top: 4rem; }
  .nav-btn::before, .nav-btn::after {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 2px;
    width: 4.5rem;
    content: "";
    display: block; }
  .nav-btn::before {
    transform: translateY(-1.5rem); }
  .nav-btn::after {
    transform: translateY(1.3rem); }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 62.5em) {
    .nav-btn {
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-right: 3rem; }
      .nav-btn::before {
        transform: translateY(-1.2rem); }
      .nav-btn::after {
        transform: translateY(1rem); } }

.header {
  background-color: #54483A;
  grid-column: full-start / col-end 6;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(16, 29, 44, 0.93), rgba(16, 29, 44, 0.93)), url(../img/hero.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  padding: 8rem;
  padding-top: 4rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr min-content minmax(6rem, min-content) 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(min-content, max-content);
  grid-row-gap: 1.5rem;
  justify-content: center; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 50em) {
    .header {
      grid-column: 1 / -1; } }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 37.5em) {
    .header {
      padding: 5rem; } }
  .header__logo {
    height: 3rem;
    justify-self: center; }
  .header__btn {
    align-self: start;
    justify-self: start; }
  .header__seenon-text {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 1.5rem;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    color: #aaa; }
    .header__seenon-text::before, .header__seenon-text::after {
      content: "";
      height: 1px;
      display: block;
      background-color: currentColor; }
  .header__seenon-logos {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 3rem;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center; }
    .header__seenon-logos img {
      max-height: 2.5rem;
      max-width: 100%;
      filter: brightness(70%); }

.realtors {
  background-color: #101d2c;
  grid-column: col-start 7 / full-end;
  padding: 3rem;
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-row-gap: 2rem; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 50em) {
    .realtors {
      grid-column: 1 / -1; } }
  .realtors__list {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: min-content max-content;
    grid-column-gap: 2rem;
    grid-row-gap: 5vh;
    align-items: center; }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 50em) {
      .realtors__list {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, min-content max-content); } }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 37.5em) {
      .realtors__list {
        grid-template-columns: min-content max-content; } }
  .realtors__img {
    width: 7rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block; }
  .realtors__sold {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #aaa;
    margin-top: -3px; }

.features {
  grid-column: center-start / center-end;
  margin: 15rem 0; }
  @supports (display: grid) {
    .features {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(25rem, 1fr));
      grid-gap: 6rem;
      align-items: start; } }

.feature {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3333%;
  margin-bottom: 6rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 1.5rem;
  grid-column-gap: 2.5rem; }
  @supports (display: grid) {
    .feature {
      width: auto;
      margin-bottom: 0; } }
  .feature__icon {
    fill: #c69963;
    width: 4.5rem;
    height: 4.5rem;
    grid-row: 1 / span 2;
    transform: translateY(-1rem); }
  .feature__text {
    font-size: 1.7rem; }

.story__pictures {
  background-color: #c69963;
  grid-column: full-start / col-end 4;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(198, 153, 99, 0.5), rgba(198, 153, 99, 0.5)), url(../img/back.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  align-items: center; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 50em) {
    .story__pictures {
      grid-column: 1 / -1;
      padding: 6rem; } }

.story__img--1 {
  width: 100%;
  grid-row: 2 / 6;
  grid-column: 2 / 6;
  box-shadow: 0 2rem 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 50em) {
    .story__img--1 {
      grid-column: 1 / 5;
      grid-row: 1 / -1; } }

.story__img--2 {
  width: 115%;
  grid-row: 4 / 6;
  grid-column: 4 / 7;
  z-index: 20;
  box-shadow: 0 2rem 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 50em) {
    .story__img--2 {
      grid-row: 1 / -1;
      width: 100%; } }

.story__content {
  background-color: #f9f7f6;
  grid-column: col-start 5 / full-end;
  padding: 6rem 8vw;
  /*
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: flex-start;
        */
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  justify-items: start; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 50em) {
    .story__content {
      grid-column: 1 / -1;
      grid-row: 5 / 6; } }

.story__text {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-bottom: 4rem; }

.homes {
  grid-column: center-start / center-end;
  margin: 15rem 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(25rem, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 7rem; }

.home {
  background-color: #f9f7f6;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-row-gap: 3.5rem; }
  .home__img {
    width: 100%;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    z-index: 1; }
  .home__like {
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    fill: #c69963;
    height: 2.5rem;
    width: 2.5rem;
    z-index: 2;
    justify-self: end;
    margin: 1rem; }
  .home__name {
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: end;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 80%;
    font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1.25rem;
    background-color: #101d2c;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    transform: translateY(50%); }
  .home__location, .home__rooms {
    margin-top: 2.5rem; }
  .home__location, .home__rooms, .home__area, .home__price {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; }
    .home__location svg, .home__rooms svg, .home__area svg, .home__price svg {
      fill: #c69963;
      height: 2rem;
      width: 2rem;
      margin-right: 1rem; }
  .home__btn {
    grid-column: 1 / -1; }

.gallery {
  background-color: #f9f7f6;
  grid-column: full-start / full-end;
  display: grid;
  /*grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 5vw);*/
  grid-template: repeat(7, 5vw)/repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1.5rem; }
  .gallery__item--1 {
    grid-row: 1 / span 2;
    grid-column: 1 / span 2; }
  .gallery__item--2 {
    grid-row: 1 / span 3;
    grid-column: 3 / span 3; }
  .gallery__item--3 {
    grid-row: 1 / span 2;
    grid-column: 6 / 7; }
  .gallery__item--4 {
    grid-row: 1 / span 2;
    grid-column: 7 / -1; }
  .gallery__item--5 {
    grid-row: 3 / span 3;
    grid-column: 1 / span 2; }
  .gallery__item--6 {
    grid-row: 4 / span 2;
    grid-column: 3 / span 2; }
  .gallery__item--7 {
    grid-row: 4 / 5;
    grid-column: 5 / 6; }
  .gallery__item--8 {
    grid-row: 3 / span 2;
    grid-column: 6 / span 2; }
  .gallery__item--9 {
    grid-row: 3 / span 3;
    grid-column: 8 / -1; }
  .gallery__item--10 {
    grid-row: 6 / span 2;
    grid-column: 1 / 2; }
  .gallery__item--11 {
    grid-row: 6 / span 2;
    grid-column: 2 / span 2; }
  .gallery__item--12 {
    grid-row: 6 / span 2;
    grid-column: 4 / 5; }
  .gallery__item--13 {
    grid-row: 5 / span 3;
    grid-column: 5 / span 3; }
  .gallery__item--14 {
    grid-row: 6 / span 2;
    grid-column: 8 / -1; }
  .gallery__img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    display: block; }

.footer {
  background-color: #101d2c;
  grid-column: full-start / full-end;
  padding: 8rem; }

.nav {
  list-style: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(15rem, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  align-items: center; }
  .nav__link:link, .nav__link:visited {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    display: block;
    transition: all .2s; }
  .nav__link:hover, .nav__link:active {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
    transform: translateY(-3px); }

.copyright {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #aaa;
  margin-top: 6rem;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 70%; }
```

**Question**

When someone clicks, view properties anchor tag homesanchor. My question is why does anchor tag push the first home (Beautiful family home) and its picture/info to the right? I thought homesanchor would not take any space? 
. Also, why does the collage/gallery of images (class gallery) overlap with homes (class homes)?  Here is picture of what I am seeing [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a child element of the grid. It is no different from the divs in that respect.

Get rid of the anchor. Their use as link targets was superceeded by the `id` attribute when HTML 4 came out two decades ago.

```
<section class="homes" id="homesanchor">
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I tried it and it works. Now, I am unable to explain why  the collage/gallery of images (class gallery) overlap with homes (class homes)? Can you please explain that part also?  These are two different sections, so they should not overlap.